# How to change position of div in media screen

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change position of DIV to navbar div in media screen for mobile (<767) and when I resize browser with width more than 767, DIV does not pass in its place, but it remains where it was changed

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
</div>

<div class=site-container">
    <div class="post-buttons-top-bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
        $(".post-buttons-top-bar").appendTo(".navbar-collapse");
    }   
});
```

Comment: You need to add an `else` clause that moves the element back to its original location.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't to move back

Comment: are you just trying to move it around on the screen? Or are you also wanting to change its position in the HTML markup.

Comment: .post-buttons-top-bar DIV is child of .site-container  (I edited now). And in media screen < 767 i like to move within navbar-collapse, and in media screen >767 like to stay in it's place

Answer (score 0):

### Try this Code:

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 767){  
        $(".post-buttons-top-bar").appendTo(".navbar-collapse");
    }else if($(window).width() > 767){
        $(".navbar-collapse").after( $(".post-buttons-top-bar") );
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse"></div>
<div class="post-buttons-top-bar"></div>
```